# How to know how many times my posts have viewed using node js?

Tags: node.js, cookies, ip

My website has this functionality: Each user can upload pictures and share that with other people. Now I wanna add something next to images that shows Image Viewed times.(just like here that we can see how many times each question has viewed).
I am doing this:
whenever a picture was rendered, increment the viewed times in database. But the problem is here that a user can come and refresh the page over and over again which is not good. I have to save some data from my visitors to my database and then check whether they have viewed it before or not. Which data should I save from them? ip? cookie? what?

> NOTE: the data I want to save should be unique. For example if a user view a post with his pc, data should differ from the data coming if he viewed with  his iPhone. In another word : each device should send unique data.

I really appreciate it if you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you only want to handle the page refresh, right? Because user might view the image every 10 minutes or every hour or everyday. And, you would count that as a view to the respective image. Now, having any unique identification mechanism like ip or cookie or something, would either allow you to add a count to the image only once or you might come out with another mechanism to handle this case.

I would simply suggest you to allow client side restrict calls to the server in case of page refresh. Although, there is no information provided about what exactly you are using on client side, but you can use `window.onbeforeunload` and `$(window).unload(function() {});` to catch page refresh event and restrict api call in this case.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't exactly get what you mean. You said use window.onbeforeunload, but a user can come and simply press ctrl + r 20 times and increment the viewed times to 20. Would you show me the code for that? I use javascript, node and express.

Comment: I want my viewed functionality to be just like stackoverflow viewed functionality(for example you can see that this post has viewed 9 times).

Comment: The view increases on page refresh on stackoverflow.